# 33 Months on Death Row

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Every day, execution delayed,
Cheating death creatively,
Bearing children blissfully,
A clever eloquent girl finally earns exoneration.

Who am I?

Bonus:

> There are 2 different ways to reach the same answer.  What are they?

Comment: Maybe not relevant, but rot13(vs lbh pyvpx rqvg lbh pna frr n 's#' jvguva <> va zvqqyr bs gur "svanyyl")

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bonus:

> The initial letters of the words spell out the musical theme of Rimsky-Korsakov's famous symphonic suite. (Specifically, the theme corresponding to Scheherazade herself, usually given to the violin.)
>  [image]

Note:

> For what it's worth, I didn't see Zoir's comment until after writing the above :-).

Comment: Funny, I noticed the pattern rot13(bs abgrf va vavgvny yrggref) and I rot13(juvfgyrq vg bhg ybhq) but I didn't recognize rot13(gur zrybql).

Comment: I wish I could give out two check marks, but this is the answer I want be on top so I gave it to you.  The picture really helps to illustrate the notes, thanks for that.

Answer (score 19):

I would think this refers to

> [Scheherazade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheherazade), who told a story every night for 1001 nights (33 months), always leaving off at a cliffhanger so that she would not be killed the next day.

Comment: Want to try for the bonus now?